# I can't boot any distro from USB / CD to install or to use it live

Tags: boot, live-usb, crash, livecd

I have a very old PC and i want to bring it back to life.

**SPECS:**
*-Pentium 4, 3.00 ghz
-1,5 GB RAM
-nVidia Geforce GT210, 1GB*

I decided to install a stable distro like **LINUX MINT XFCE 32-bit**. I tried with an **USB 4GB FAT32** using three programs "**Linux live USB Creator**", "**ubootnetin**" and "**Rufus**" but with none of this worked. Then **I burned a DVD** but with no luck. No matter what if i use USB or DVD i get this **error when i try to boot**. From what I read on forums, I found something about **"nomodeset"** and i can't modify this because it never gets me to install menu or GRUB loader.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that you have a 32-bit, and not a 64-bit, installation / liveCD?

Comment: It was 32-bit, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the contemporary Linux distributions/the Linux kernel just do not support a Pentium 4 anymore.

A great alternative is using FreeBSD instead for having a modern supported Unix with regular updates.

see https://www.freebsd.org/

PS. I have got an old netbook from 2009, and I am doing the same thing.